# Protected $view values inside template_views_pre_render function?

Tags: views, hooks, 8

I'm trying to alter the view page title by using the *template*_views_pre_render function inside *mytemplate*.theme file.
It works fine, I'm able to modify its title this way:

```
$view->build_info['title'] = ...
```

My issue now is that I need to restrict this action to only one specific view, so I simply need to check the view id.
I tried with `if ($view->id == 'my_view_id') {...}` but I realized I can't access the $view values because they are protected.
How can I implement this control here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the value of the view object you can use the method `get()`:

```
$view->get('id')
```

Or if the object provides a special method for the id, which is the case with the view object:

```
$view->id()
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was trying to understand.